# Get AngularJS object property name in the markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have an object:

```
$scope.Golovkin = {
    id:12,
    Like:0,
    Dislike:0,
    url:"https://twitter.com/GGGBoxing"
};
```

And in the view I have a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="incrementLikes(Golovkin)" />
```

How do I replace the `value` of the button with the property name of `$scope.Golovkin.Like` as a string?

Comment: What is use case for needing to do this?

Comment: Numerous people played with this without success....bottom line is you need to outline higher level problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" ng-model="Golovkin.Like" ng-click="incrementLikes(Golovkin)" />
```

Comment: Doesn't ng-model bind the **value** of HTML controls?

Answer (score 0):

You need the name "Like" on the button. That is the second property of the object.You need a function through which you can return the property name by index.

```
 $scope.getKeyName = function(obj, idx) {
            return Object.keys(obj)[idx];
    }
```

Now use this to get the name on the view

```
<input type="button" value={{getKeyName(Golovkin, 1)}} ng-click="incrementLikes(Golovkin)" />
```

Comment: I get it now but not so sure angular will evaluate this in view without assigning `Object` to scope.

Comment: Yes - probably `$scope.Object = Object` might be needed in the controller.

Comment: Actually throws an angular error not allowed to use `Object` in view even as scope. try it

Comment: Also can run into order of keys problem due to objects not having order. This really isn't solid at all and would suggest OP re-think what they are trying to do at a higher level

Comment: Of course. Despite the answer could loosely address the problem, op should adopt a better design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<button>`, for example:
`<button ng-click="incrementCount()">{{Golovkin.Like}}</button>`

Here is an example with a counting number: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xie_qianyue/10ognrk1/).

**EDIT:**

You can save the properties' name in an array, when your controller is initialized:

```
$scope.buttonName = Object.keys($scope.Golovkin);
```

and display that name as :

```
<button ng-click="incrementCount()">{{buttonName[1]}}</button>
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xie_qianyue/5yx36ro4/).

Comment: I already deleted this identical same solution using `<button>`. OP wants the property name itself to display...not the value ....  *"how to get the property name?"*

Comment: u just can't do something like `<button ng-click="incrementCount()">Like</button>`, as Like is the property name.

Comment: please see my updates, keeping the properties name in an array would solve your problem.

Comment: Not really because Objects have no order so you can't be sure what index to use

Comment: You know how many properties in that Object? And what kind of property should be? It would be a property "Tiger" for example?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method [Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objName)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames#Examples).

Here's a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.Golovkin = {
    id: 12,
    Like: 0,
    Dislike: 0,
    url: "https://twitter.com/GGGBoxing"
  };

  $scope.getProperty = function(property) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames($scope.Golovkin).find(x => x == property);
  }

  $scope.incrementLikes = function(Golovkin) {
    Golovkin.Like++;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>      
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="button" value="{{ getProperty('Like') }}" ng-click="incrementLikes(Golovkin)">
  <!-- <button ng-click="incrementLikes(Golovkin)"><span ng-bind="getProperty('Like')"></span></button> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is way over the top! If OP knows the term `'Like'` to be able to pass to function why would they need a function to reproduce it?

Comment: Well, since it's just an example, the parameter of the function should not be standard. And if we think this way, none of the given answers are correct, even the Charlie H.'s answer, because you don't know if the search property is always in the 1st. index.

Comment: Whole question is probably an XY problem. But yours isn't any more right either since it requires knowing the value that they want output anyway